# Functional Testing won't work with Nested Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, functional-testing

First post on stackoverflow, apologies beforehand for anything noob-like.

I have been receiving an error on one of my functional tests and after many hours, I just can't seem to figure out how to pass it.

In short, an `invoice_schedule` which `has_many` `invoice_milestones`. Then, `invoice_milestones` has an attribute, `estimate_percentage` (an integer). My model `models/invoice_schedule.rb` has a validation which requires the sum of all `estimate_percentages` must equal 100.

The functional test for the `invoice_schedule` create action fails every time. With my current code below it has been erroring out instead. I can't see how it would error out with the params I'm passing.

I'll also note that `estimate has_one :invoice_schedule`

Any help or suggestions are appreciated :)

models/invoice_schedule.rb:

```
class InvoiceSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :estimate
    has_many :invoice_milestones, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_milestones, :allow_destroy => true

    validate :total_must_equal_one_hundred_percent

    def total_must_equal_one_hundred_percent
        if total_percent != 100
            errors.add(:invoice_milestones, "Total must equal 100%")
        end
    end

    def total_percent
        invoice_milestones.to_a.sum { |item| item.estimate_percentage || 0 }
    end
end
```

models/invoice_milestone.rb:

```
class InvoiceMilestone < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :invoice_schedule
    belongs_to :invoice

    validates :estimate_percentage, :numericality => {:only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100}
end
```

controllers/invoice_schedules_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @invoice_schedule = InvoiceSchedule.new(params[:invoice_schedule])
    @estimate = Estimate.find_by_id(params[:estimate_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice_schedule.save
        format.html { redirect_to invoice_schedule_path(@invoice_schedule), :flash => {:notice => 'Invoice schedule was successfully created.', :status => 'success'} }
        format.json { render json: @invoice_schedule, status: :created, location: @invoice_schedule }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @invoice_schedule.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

test/functional/invoice_schedules_controller_test.rb

```
  setup do
    @account = accounts(:lorem)
    @estimate = estimates(:lorem_one)
    @user = users(:lorem_vendor)
    @request.host = "#{@account.subdomain}.myapp.local"
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    @invoice_schedule = invoice_schedules(:lorem_one)
    @invoice_milestone = invoice_milestones(:lorem_one)
    @data_estimate = estimates(:lorem_two)
    @data_invoice_schedule = @invoice_schedule.attributes.merge({estimate_id: @data_estimate.id})
  end

  test "should create invoice_schedule" do
    assert_difference('InvoiceSchedule.count') do
        post :create, :invoice_schedule => { estimate_id: @data_estimate, :invoice_milestone => {estimate_percentage: 100}}
    end

    assert_redirected_to estimate_invoice_schedule_path(@estimate, assigns(:invoice_schedule))
  end
```

config/routes.rb

```
require 'subdomain'

    Accountimize::Application.routes.draw do

      resources :invoices do
        member do
          get 'generateInvoiceFromMilestone'
        end
      end

      resources :users
      resources :sessions

      get "sign_up" => "accounts#new", :as => "sign_up"

      resources :accounts

      resources :clients do
        get :client_address, on: :member
      end

      resources :estimates do
        resources :invoice_schedules, :shallow => true
      end

      resources :line_items

      constraints(Subdomain) do
        match '/' => 'accounts#show'
        get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
        get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
        get "register" => "users#new", :as => "register"
      end
      root :to => 'site#index', :as => 'site'
    end
```

The trace of the error I get:

```
InvoiceSchedulesControllerTest
     test_should_create_invoice_schedule                                 ERROR
        No route matches {:invoice_schedule=>{:estimate_id=>"706507935", :invoice_milestones_attributes=>{"0"=>{:description=>"test", :estimate_percentage=>"100"}}}, :controller=>"invoice_schedules", :action=>"create"}
        STDERR:
        Exception `ActionController::RoutingError' at /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:465:in `raise_routing_error'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:461:in `rescue in generate'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:453:in `generate'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:494:in `generate'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:490:in `generate_extras'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:486:in `extra_keys'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:145:in `assign_parameters'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:438:in `process'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `process'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:370:in `post'
        test/functional/invoice_schedules_controller_test.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <class:InvoiceSchedulesControllerTest>'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/assertions.rb:55:in `assert_difference'
        test/functional/invoice_schedules_controller_test.rb:30:in `block in <class:InvoiceSchedulesControllerTest>'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `block in run'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:444:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        /Users/Matt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in `run'
```

I've tried quite a few other ways to accomplish adding an invoice_milestone to a newly created invoice_schedule in the functional test, however nothing seems to have worked for me. Why would I receive the above routing error if accepts_nested_attributes_for is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this. First you need to get the routing side right. Because you've nested invoice schedules inside estimates you need to supply an `estimate_id` at the top level (not inside `params[:invoice_schedules]`), i.e.

```
post :create, :estimate_id => @data_estimate.id, :invoice_schedule => {...}
```

The expectation is then that you controller does something along the lines of

```
estimate = Estimate.find(params[:estimate_id])
@invoice_schedule = estimate.invoice_schedules.build params[:invoice_schedule]
```

The second part is to do with nested attributes - you need to provide a params hash that matches what Rails expects. The first part of that is that the key in the hash should be `:invoice_milestones_attributes`. Since this is a `has_many`, the corresponding value needs
 to be an array of hashes, or a hash of hashes (the keys are ignored - this is largely present because of interaction between arrays and hashes in a rails' parameter passing), for example

```
post :create, :estimate_id => @data_estimate.id, 
              :invoice_schedule => {
                :invoice_milestones_attributes => [
                  {:estimate_percentage => 100}
                ]
              }
```

Comment: Thanks very much! However, my test is now failing I've used the following line for the test: 

post :create, :estimate_id => @data_estimate.id, :invoice_schedules => { :invoice_milestones_attributes => {0 => {estimate_percentage: 100}}}

The test fails because of the total_must_equal_one_hundred_percent validation. Commenting it out makes the test pass.

However, removing this validation and adding a validation to ensure an invoice_schedule has at least one invoice_milestone causes the test to fail, which suggests that the invoice_milestone attributes are not creating a new invoice_milestone.

Comment: You could stick a breakpoint in there to see what is actually happening, rather than trying to infer it

Comment: That helped trace it back. Thanks very much for the help!